# How to send o365 account-info-email when created via powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

When I create a user for o365 using powershell, what do I do to get the system to send that automated message containing their account information?

I already know how to send an email via powershell, but that isn't what I want to do here.

I am looking for a command that sends the system-generated account-info email to a specific email address that I specify (like it does in the admin GUI).

Here is how I create the user account:

```
New-MsolUser -DisplayName "Some Body" -FirstName Some -LastName Body -UserPrincipalName somebody@anywhere.com -UsageLocation US -LicenseAssignment mydomain:STANDARDWOFFPACK}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command in powershell for Office365 that will send the system-generated account info message.

This means that you need to create your own p[owershell routine](http://www.cgoosen.com/2015/04/user-powershell-to-bulk-email-your-users/) that emails your users with the message you want.

It is possible to make the system auto-generate the passwords, which you can then export to csv and load them back into your script to include in the emails you send to the users.